# Redis FLUSHALL keeps 2 keys named `processes` and `domain.com:port:hash`

Tags: linux, redis

I'm using RubyOnRails as a base for an online shop and redis client library gem. After alert from my hosting provider I have decided to secure the redis and flush entire DB in order to rerun caching and etc.

But strange things happening for me, cause after running:

`127.0.0.1:6379> FLUSHALL
OK`

And then checking for existing keys I got:

`127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "processes"
2) "mydomain.com:5digitport:strangehash"`

I'm not a Redis expert, but I thing something wrong with my Redis instance.
Have anyone faced this problem and how should I solve it?

Comment: Pls remove tags ruby and ruby-on-rails as question is not related to those topics

Comment: @WandMaker I agree that this is not related to ruby and ruby-on-rails but a lot of people are using the same mechanism of caching of RoR apps and client library also written in ruby so, they can be a good reference for those who already faced the problem using the same config. Will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app (or another one) is still connecting to redis and writing keys. Inspect your `CLIENT LIST` or netstat for connections.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are using a hosting provider that deploys Redis for you, and they've stored some config details in your Redis instance. If so, then you may not be able to delete these keys. If so, then just ignore them.